# what do the tape contents of a turing machine look like after halting?

Tags: turing-machines

what do the tape contents of Turing machine look like after halting? Are there empty symbols after the qaccept or reject?

Comment: The tape contents is completely arbitrary — the tape is left as is when the Turing machine halts. The states $q_{\mathrm{accept}},q_{\mathrm{reject}}$ that you mention do *not* appear on the tape, so your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The tape contains whatever the Turing machine wants it to. There's no rule that says it has to have certain contents. It must have a finite number of symbols, and all the spaces outside of a finite region must be blank.

Comment: I am not an expert at this. But if TM is solving a Decision Problem, then I think it okay if tape contents are arbitrary. But for function problems, the TM's tape contents might represent the optimal function output. Am I making sense?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Yes, they should, if the TM is solving a function problem. If it's solving a decision problem then it should also halt with a yes or no output on the tape.

Comment: For decision problem, TM do not need to output yes or no on the tape. It can simply be in qaccept or qreject state right?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Sure... that is equivalent, because we can edit the TM so it writes a 1 in qaccept state and writes a 0 in qreject state and then goes to a final state. Likewise if we have a TM that writes 1 or 0 and then halts, we can edit it so it goes to an accept or reject state depending on whether the thing it wrote was a 1 or a 0